# Llamar a un script.js desde html. ¿Más rapido mediante ruta relativa?

Tags: javascript, html

Me estoy planteando cómo optimizar la velocidad de carga de una página web y me preguntaba cuál de estas dos opciones para llamar a un fichero js externo, pero ubicado en el mismo servidor, sería más rápida:

1. Fichero en **https://web.com/carpeta/index.html** llama a **script.js** así:

```html
<script src="https://web.com/carpeta/js/script.js"></script>
```

2. El mismo fichero index.html anterior llama a script.js así:

```html
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

¿Sería más rápido el segundo caso porque el primero está haciendo una petición HTTP o sería indiferente? ¿Alguien tiene alguna experiencia?

Comment: Ambas realizan una solicitud `HTTP`, en la primera esta explicito y en la segunda, no.

Comment: A menos que tu fichero tenga miles de lineas de código, optimizar la carga del mismo no hará mucha diferencia. Por otro lado, existen métodos de ofuscación y minimizado para *comprimir* el archivo a un tamaño menor. Y si no deseas una petición `HTTP` adicional, siempre puedes incrustar tu código en el mismo `html`. Saludos

Comment: La mejor forma seria optimizar el código del script, de otra manera no hay diferencia en como hagas la llamada al mismo.

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios